# What are symbols as opposed to text, and how can I convert them to paths?

Tags: svg, inkscape

When I export an ER diagram in MySQL Workbench as SVG, its text uses `<symbol>` tags. This makes it impossible to copy the tables to another file, without breaking the layout. (The copied object will be a group containing a path, but the letters are too small in relation to the text.)

So I would like to convert the text to paths.
But if I try *Object > Convert to path*,
I get an error message.
([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MVWI.gif) is a GIF that shows it in German.)

Does anyone know a way to force the conversion to paths? (Or any other solution to this problem?)

Comment: `<symbol>` elements are [used to define graphical template objects which can be instantiated by a `<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol). If the `<symbol>` element has a viewBox attribute the `<use>` element can get a position (x,y) and a size (width, height) meaning that you can set the size of the text to something bigger. It would be nice to see the svg code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit > Clone > Unlink Clone* will turn each symbol into a group containing a path.